# Macro for editing data

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for Macro VBA code for performing the following actions, which I am required to do manually almost everyday.

I am writing down the steps which I have to do manually so that process is clear to the users replying to this query:

1. Copy from a .txt file and paste in excel workbook data,  which looks like this
   LT Insulators – Shackle Insulators – Wipro Industries
   Lightning Arrestors – Elpro International
   Conductors – ACSR Raccoon – HHI Industries
   The data is pasted in Column A. This data is of variable length and can be between 500-700 rows.
2. Use Text to Columns (Delimited with ‘-‘ as separator) to distribute the data in Col A and B where there are 2 phrases and C where there are 3 phrases. Where there are 2 phrases, I need the data in Col B to move to Column C (as this is the Col for Makes). For 2 phrase data, after the Text to Columns action , Col C will remain blank and probably that should be the criterion for moving the data from Col B to Col C. After this step, the table should look like this :
   LT Insulators   Shackle Insulators  Wipro Industries
   Lightning Arrestors     Elpro International
   Conductors  ACSR Raccoon    HHI Industries
3. Then I apply =TRIM() function to both Col A and C (Col B not required) since the data is from a text file. The trimmed values can be in other columns also, which can be value pasted in the original column.
4. Sort the data in column A & B with C as the sort key.

I am not very literate with macro VBA coding and therefore not been able draw the right thing up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code which returns an error of Runtime 1004. Paste method failed or something like that.

```
Sub Dataedit() ' ' Dataedit Macro ' Edits data for report '

'
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1:A154").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 27
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 28.57
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 31.29
    Range("B1:B11").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C1:C11")
    Range("C1:C11").Select
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 15.43
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("B13:B14").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C13:C14")
    Range("B18:B19").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C18:C19")
    Range("C18:C19").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("B27:B28").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C27:C28")
    Range("B30:B32").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C30:C32")
    Range("C30:C32").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("B36:B45").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C36:C45")
    Range("C36:C45").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Range("B46:B53").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C46:C53")
    Range("C46:C53").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("B55:B62").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C55:C62")
    Range("C55:C62").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=12
    Range("B64:B67").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C64:C67")
    Range("C64:C67").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=30
    Range("B94:B104").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C94:C104")
    Range("B105").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C105")
    Range("C105").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=27
    Range("B128:B136").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C128:C136")
    Range("C128:C136").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-147
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-4])"
    Range("F3").Select
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 20.71
    Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 27.71
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-3])"
    Range("E1:F1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E1:F154"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("E1:F154").Select
    Range("F160").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-183
    Range("E1:E154").Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    Range("E5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("F4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("E1:E154").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("F1:F154").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D15").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("E1:F154").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("D11").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-51
    Range("A1:C154").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C154") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1:C154") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C154")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=81
    ChDir "D:\"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\File List.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("E10").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save End Sub
```

Comment: SO is not designed to provide you code, it is for **you to write** your own code and get help with it.

Comment: Help us to help you.  **post your current code.**

Comment: I recommend that you (in a first step) record the things you want Excel to do for you with the VBA macro recorder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_HQGHPBYoo Afterwards, have a look at the code and try to understand it by highlighting VBA key-words and pressing `F1`. Also, I'd recommend reading this: http://www.homeandlearn.org/ Afterwards you should be set to provide a first solution to the above problem yourself. If you're still having problems, feel free to come back here and ask for specific advice on something you have attempted to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my take. Not sure if the paste is working as it should.

I've avoided the use of select as it only slows down the code. I've also trimmed the data from columns A & C in situ rather than copying it over to E & F columns.

I've assumed that the data is in a workbook called Book1. You can of course rename the workbook and worksheet in the macro.

```
Sub DataEdit()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim GCell As Range
Dim NumberOfRowsOfData, Count As Integer

Set wb = Workbooks("Book1")
    With wb
    Set ws = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With ws
        Set GCell = .Range("A1")
            GCell.PasteSpecial
            GCell.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Set GCell = .Range("A:A")
            NumberOfRowsOfData = .Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
            GCell.ColumnWidth = 27
        Set GCell = .Range("B:B")
            GCell.ColumnWidth = 28.57
        Set GCell = .Range("C:C")
            GCell.ColumnWidth = 31.29
        For Count = 1 To NumberOfRowsOfData
            If .Cells(Count, 3) = "" Then
                .Cells(Count, 3).Value = Cells(Count, 2).Value
                .Cells(Count, 2).ClearContents
                .Cells(Count, 1).Value = Trim(.Cells(Count, 1).Value)
                .Cells(Count, 3).Value = Trim(.Cells(Count, 3).Value)
            End If
        Range("A1:C" & NumberOfRowsOfData).Sort key1:=Range("C1:C" & NumberOfRowsOfData), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        Next Count
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Chris for replying to my query. The code works like a charm. Could you please tell me how to select this as the best answer. I regret the delay in posting the feedback

Comment: I think you've succeeded in selecting it. Thanks.